# How to do an Excel Addin for iPad?

Tags: excel, ipad, excel-formula, office-js

I know it looks a superficial question, but I really would like to know how to start developing addins for excel on Ipads. What should I download and how to install my addins into an iPad? I didn't find this on google...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to introduce you the office JS add-in,
You can use the Office Add-ins platform to build solutions that extend Office applications and interact with content in Office documents. Your solution can run in Office across multiple platforms, including Windows, Mac, iPad, and in a browser.

I would recommend you to create an Office Add-in by using the [Yeoman generator for Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator)

You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac) for sideloading your add-in solution in IPad

And debug your add-in on iPad can be found at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac)